# Python: filter dataframe so only rows that contain specific text in specific column remains

Tags: python, text, filtering, subset

I have a dataframe called df_responses_2.  See picture below :

[image]

In the Duplicate column I have "False" and "True" values.  I want to create a new dataframe called df_responses_3 that only contains rows that show "False" under Duplicate column.

I tried the following code below but it did not execute correctly:

> df_responses_3 = df_responses_2[(df_responses_2['Duplicate'] ==
>   "False")]
>
> df_responses_3

The code above only returns the header row...and nothing else.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking off the `"` around False. It could be stored as a `False` boolean instead of the string `'False'`